# I want to change the author name

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, author

I have a website where I am mostly posting translations. Therefore, I want to show name of the author of the original post instead of me on the author name area. How can I do this?

Comment: If you aren't writing original content and are just translating to another language, you may just need to add a link to the original post in the post body and/or the author name.

Comment: I would use https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-author/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three possible approaches:

1. A normal WP installation already has [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) which you can add to your post. So you could use those to add the original author's name to. The only problem is that general themes usually do not display `the_meta`, because they do not know what to expect. In your case you would want to replace `the_author` in your theme with `the_meta` (don't mess with the original theme files, use a child theme!)
2. Easier, but a bit hacky: add the original authors to the user list. They don't need to know they have an account, just provide bogus e-mail addresses and don't let WP send their password to them. Now you can simply assign them as authors and they will have their own author page as well.
3. The most thorough approach is [adding a meta box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) yourself (or use a [plugin like WCK](https://ido.wordpress.org/plugins-wp/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/)). This gives you complete control on how to insert the information in your child theme.

Comment: Considering my level of coding knowledge, I chose second solution :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The

> the_author()

function should return the name of the author of the post. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author .

Your theme will have to use that function in the loop that displays the post meta.

Comment: I believe @Hikmet rather means to imply that they translate posts and content from other sources - rather than having their WordPress user listed as the author of every post, they would like it to display the author of the original, untranslated content (who does not have a WordPress user account for the site in question)

Comment: That may be true, @bosco . Whatever process he uses to 'scrape' content from another place will need to grab the author name, then change their theme to display that value. I don't know if you can insert a name into the author field of the post table without that user existing in the site. So, more info needed on the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new author or user in wordpress and then just change the author from post quick edit option to that original author

Answer (score -1):

the_author();

this function will return author name, you can change it on below path.

Go to your database -> users table -> change (display_name)